# Baked Displacement map from multi-res completely flat gray

Tags: texture-baking, displacement

[image]It worked fine but after uv editing and I dont know what it just went gray, normal map still works fine.
I tried scaling it, changing multi-res level, … i dont know what else to try

Comment: Hi and welcome :) please [add some images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/197478/edit) to your question so that other users can see what you see. :) Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: I have the same issue as well, but no solution. :/
I see you have viewport for multires above zero, which I also heard could cause it.